# How to remove the three dot move grabber from Notification area in MATE

Tags: linux, manjaro, mate, main-desktop-panel

I have a fresh install of Manjaro using MATE, and I can't for the life of me find out how to remove these dots that show up on the Window List and Notification Area panel applets. I've installed MATE through Ubuntu before, but never on Manjaro. I don't remember seeing these before. Is there a way to remove these?

[image: Here is an example of what I'm talking about.]

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to remove the 3 dot icon from it but not how to make it any less wide. Here's what I did in case someone else stumbles upon this later:

```bsh
# Remove the ugly drag handles from panel applets

cp -R /usr/share/themes/Arc-Darker/ ~/.themes
cat << 'CSS' >> ~/.themes/Arc-Darker/gtk-3.0/gtk.css

MatePanelAppletFrameDBus > MatePanelAppletFrameDBus {
    background: none;
}
CSS
```

What this is doing is you copy the theme's folder that you're using from `/usr/share/themes` to the `.themes` folder in your home directory and edit `~/.themes/Arc-Darker/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` file with the CSS shown above. I first just tried creating a `gtk-3.0` folder in `~/.themes/` but that didn't work.