# How to remove three dots on Fedora Mate panels

Tags: fedora, mate, fedora-37

I have the same question as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1453354/how-to-remove-the-three-dot-move-grabber-from-notification-area-in-mate). Unfortunately, what that user did did not work for me. I tried adding the CSS to these four files: `gtk-3.0/gtk.css`, `gtk-3.0/gtk-dark.css`, `gtk-4.0/gtk.css`, and `gtk-4.0/gtk-dark.css`. Unfortunately, the dots are still there on the panels.